# Factorisation of the sum of $n$ squares using hypercomplex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, factoring, sums-of-squares, hypercomplex-numbers

After finding out that you could factor $a^2 + b^2$ as $(a+bi)(a-bi)$ using complex numbers I wondered if there were any useful factoring tricks using the quaternions or octonions and after some playing around I found that you could factor the sum of up to $4$ squares using this formula: $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2 = (a+bi+cj+dk)(a-bi-cj-dk)$$ where $i,j,k$ are the complex units used by the quaternions and $a,b,c,d$ are real constants. Now, I am not too familiar with octonions and any of the ones above that, so my question is:

> Can you extend this formula to the octonions or sedenions and all of the ones above that to factor the sum of $n$ squares? If yes, how? If no, is there anything similar that might be useful?

Comment: I tried doing this with octonions and after multiplying them out manually i've concluded that this extensions works aswell. Still looking for a general formula for n-squares though

Comment: I tried using some calculator to try some examples but it only worked for quaternions and not for octonions, I am somewhat confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that $z$ is an octonion, so $z \in \mathbb{O}$ aka $z \in \left\{ \mathbb{R},\, \mathbb{C},\, \mathbb{H},\, \mathbb{O} \right\}$, and that $\overline{z}$ is a conjugate $z$, then:
$$
\begin{align*}
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \overline{z} \cdot z \tag{1.1} \label{eq: 1.1}\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \left| z \right|^{2} \tag{1.2} \label{eq: 1.2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

aka if $z := x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right]$ where $x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i_{k}$ are the imaginary units:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(  x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) &= \left(  x_{0} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \tag{2.1} \label{eq: 2.1}\\
\left(  x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{7}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{7}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] \tag{2.2} \label{eq: 2.2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

##### Derivation Options

###### Octonions

If $z \in \mathbb{R}$, then the formula is trivial. If $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then the formula follows directly from [*difference of two squares is a squared*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares), and $z \in \mathbb{H}$ then follows from [*Euler Four-Square Identity*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFour-SquareIdentity.html) and at $z \in \mathbb{O}$ the formula from [*Degen's Eight-Square Identity*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DegensEight-SquareIdentity.html) follows. The identitys also follows from the fact that the norm of the product of two complex numbers, quaternions or octonions is the product of the norms. It also follows directly from their vector representations with real components and the Euclidean norm.

Hurwitz's proved that (as you can see here: Hurwitz's theorem of composition algebras - there are multible proves on the page).

For another reference see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Conjugate,_norm,_and_inverse).

###### Sedenions and beyond

Define:
$$
\begin{align*}
z &:= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

Rewrtie $z \cdot \overline{z}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \left( x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right)\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= x_{0}^{2} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right]\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= x_{0}^{2} - \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{k \ne g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{k} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right] - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] \right)\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{k \ne g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{k} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right]\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] - \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{k < g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{k} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right] + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{k > g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{k} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right] \right) \tag{use $i_{m} \cdot i_{n} = - i_{n} \cdot i_{m}$ when $m \ne n \wedge \left\{ m,\, n \right\} \notin \left\{ 0 \right\}$}\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] - \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{k > g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{k} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right] - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ \sum\limits_{k > g = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot x_{g} \cdot i_{k} \cdot i_{g} \right] \right] \right)\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

So the formula applies for all algebras of the Cayley–Dickson construction (from $\mathbb{R}$).

Youn can find a calculator for stuff like that [here](https://jwbales.us/sedenion.html).

##### Other Hypercomplex Numbers with Similar Formulas

###### Dual Numbers

$z$ is a dual number if $z = a + b \cdot \varepsilon \wedge \varepsilon^{2} = 0 \ne \varepsilon \wedge \left\{ a,\, b \right\} \in \mathbb{R}$. A similar formular is:
$$
\begin{align*}
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \overline{z} \cdot z\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \left( a + b \cdot \varepsilon \right) \cdot \left( a - b \cdot \varepsilon \right)\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= a^{2} - \left( b \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{2} = a^{2} - b^{2} \cdot \varepsilon^{2} = a^{2} - b^{2} \cdot 0 = a^{2}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
a^{2} &= \left( a + b \cdot \varepsilon \right) \cdot \left( a - b \cdot \varepsilon \right)\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

###### Split-Hypercomplex Numbers (only composition algrbras)

A split hypercomplex number $z$ is of the form $z = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \wedge 8 \geq 2^{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ where $i_{\geq n}^{2} = 1 \ne i_{\geq n}^{2} \wedge i_{< n}^{2} = -1$, $i_{0} = 1$, ... So:

$$
\begin{align*}
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \overline{z} \cdot z\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \left( x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right)\\
z \cdot \overline{z} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{n - 1} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] -  \sum\limits_{k = 2^{n - 1}}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right]
\end{align*}
$$
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] -  \sum\limits_{k = n}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k}^{2} \right] &= \left( x_{0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2^{n} - 1}\left[ x_{k} \cdot i_{k} \right] \right)\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

- [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number#Conjugate,_modulus,_and_bilinear_form): $x_{0}^{2} - x_{1} = \left( x_{0} + x_{1} \cdot i_{1} \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - x_{1} \cdot i_{1} \right)$
- [split-quaternionen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion#Properties): $x_{0}^{2} + x_{1} - x_{2} - x_{3} = \left( x_{0} + x_{1} \cdot i_{1} + x_{2} \cdot i_{2} + x_{3} \cdot i_{3} \right) \cdot \left( x_{0} - x_{1} \cdot i_{1} - x_{2} \cdot i_{2} - x_{3} \cdot i_{3} \right)$
- [split-octonion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion#Conjugate,_norm_and_inverse): ...

###### Bi-Hypercomplex Numbers (only composition algrbras)

Some bi-hypercomplex numbers have similar formulas like [bi-quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion#Properties) and [bi-octanions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioctonion)...

Comment: Holy, thanks for that essay length explanation mate! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I just tried some examples for sedonions and somehow the formula worked, to be fair I did strictly use the units in order and didn‘t leave any gaps like you did in your example but it still worked. Typing your example into it also resulted in 4 instead of 228, so something seems to be wrong somewhere. No clue where though

Comment: @hefe You're right. I was just arguing why the derivation of the formula no longer uses the norm or the Euclidean norm of the vector representation of these numbers, instead of disproving the existence of the formula (which is not possible, because it exists). I corrected it.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, you really saved me a lot of computation with this answer mate. Thanks again!